how to instantiate a new Sharp.js object for each path to GeoTIFF file
for the code posted below, in the code in the section titled code_1, I invoke the method subtractGeoTIFFs(). The first two parameters passed to the latter method, contain two
paths to two different GeoTIFFs taken in two different time series. Both GeoTIFFs are with indentical width and height and number of channels.
Both of the GeoTIFFs contain different values of NDVI. I confirmed constrasted contents of both of the GeoTIFFs by importing it and open it in QGIS.
Now, i want to subtract the contents of the GeoTIFFs  and write the resultant GeoTIFF of the subtraction to the local disk using sharp.
The problem I am facing with sharp, is that despite the first two parametes passed to the method subtractGeoTIFFs belong to two different GeoTIFFs, when the execution of the code
reaches the following loop "as mentioned below":
for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    const ndviValue = (data1[i]/255) - ((data2[i])/255);
    resultBuffer[i] = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, ndviValue));
    console.log('xcx data1[i]:', data1[i]/255)
    console.log('xcx data2[i]:', data2[i]/255)
    console.log('xcx resultBuffer[i]:', resultBuffer[i])
}

the first two log statments print identical values for data1[i] and data2[i], and consequently, the difference is always zeor despite both are two different GeoTIFFs.
Am I initializing image1 and image2 incorrectly? why that is happening? and how to solve it please?
code_1:
dirsInfoForIndividualBandsForTS1.map((dir, index) => {
    if (dir.includes(SysConstants.CONST_BAND_1_TOKEN.description) && dirsInfoForIndividualBandsForTS2[index].includes(SysConstants.CONST_BAND_1_TOKEN.description)) {
        TIFFUtils.subtractGeoTIFFs(dirsInfoForIndividualBandsForTS1[0], dirsInfoForIndividualBandsForTS2[0], outputDirForDeltaTS1TS2, outputForDeltaTS1TS2ForBand1);
    }

subtractGeoTIFFs()
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    IOUtils.buildPath(pathToOutputDir)
    .then(async constructedPathToOutput=> {
        const image1 = sharp(pathToGeoTIFFForTS1);
        const data1 = await image1.toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: false });
        const metadata1 = await image1.metadata();

        const image2 = sharp(pathToGeoTIFFForTS2);
        const data2 = await image2.toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: false });
        const metadata2 = await image2.metadata();

        if (metadata1.width === metadata2.width) {
            if (metadata1.height === metadata2.height) {
                if (metadata1.channels === metadata2.channels) {

                    const resultBuffer = new Float32Array(metadata1.width * metadata1.height * metadata1.channels);

                    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
                        const ndviValue = (data1[i]/255) - ((data2[i])/255);
                        resultBuffer[i] = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, ndviValue));
                        console.log('xcx data1.data[i]:', data1[i]/255)
                        console.log('xcx data2.data[i]:', data2[i]/255)
                        console.log('xcx resultBuffer[i]:', resultBuffer[i])
                    }
                    await sharp(Buffer.from(resultBuffer.buffer), {
                        raw: {
                            width: metadata1.width,
                            height: metadata1.height,
                            channels: metadata1.channels,
                        }
                    }).toFile(constructedPathToOutput + '\\' + outputFileName);
                    resolve(constructedPathToOutput + '\\' + outputFileName);

                }
            }
        }
    });

